# Statistics - Finding the median

Tags: statistics

Problem :

x =    0-4 , 4-10 , 10-18 , 18-30 , 30-40

f(x) = 15 , 35 , 20 , 20 , 10

Finding the median?

This is that I did :

Cumulative frequency distribution :

F(x) = 15 , 50 , 70 , 90 , 100

Midpoint : 2 , 7 , 14 , 24 , 35

Formula : $Md = L_0 + \frac{\frac{n}{2}-F(x_{m-1})}{f(x_m)}*(L_1-L_0)$

n=100, $$\frac{100}{2} = 50$$

But F(x) = 50? I don't understand how to continue?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be obvious that the median should be near $10$.  Consider what proportion of the values (at least) are $10$ or below, and what proportion $10$ or above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L_0$ is the lower limit of interval, where the median is inside.

$\frac{n}{2}=50 \ \ \color{blue} \checkmark$

$F(x_{m-1})$ is the cumulative frequency below the interval of the median. It is 15

$f_{xm}$=freqency in the Intervall of the median. It is 35

$L_1$ is the upper limit of interval, where the median is inside.

$=4+\frac{50-15}{35}\cdot (10-4)=4+6$