# Median of grouped data

Tags: statistics

[image]

part (ii)

Median = $Lm +(n/2-cf)/fm*h$
       = $171+(20-16)/12*3$
       = $172$

am i correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. If you want another exercise, then you can try [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876362/statistics-finding-the-median/876396) one.